# Is there any general formula for $\sum_{i=0}^k {ai+b\choose i}$ for ${ai+b} \geq i$ and $a \in \mathbb Z$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Is there any general formula for 
    $$\sum_{i=0}^k {ai+b\choose i}$$
for  ${ai+b} \geq i$ and $a \in \mathbb Z$   ?

Comment: Have you figured out any examples?

Comment: Are you able to handle $a=0$?